# I am trying to merge two arrays and sort it in descending order

Tags: c

I am trying sort two arrays in descending order but whenever i am executing the code i am not getting the output in descending order instead its repeating the entered element again and again.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int arr1[100], arr2[100], arr3[200];
        int s1, s2, s3;
        int i, j, k;


           printf("enter the number for first array :");
           scanf("%d",&s1);

           for(i=0;i<s1;i++)
                {
              printf("element - %d : ",i);
              scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
            }

           printf("enter the number for first array :");
           scanf("%d",&s2);

           for(i=0;i<s2;i++)
                {
              printf("element - %d : ",i);
              scanf("%d",&arr2[i]);
            }

        s3 = s1 + s2;
    //here i am merging two arrays in a third int variable that is arr3
        for(i=0;i<s1; i++)
            {
                arr3[i] = arr1[i];
             }
         for(j=0;j<s2; j++)
            {
                arr3[i] = arr2[j];
                i++; 
            }

       for(i=0;i<s3; i++)
            {
               for(k=0;k<s3-1;k++)
                 {
                   if(arr3[k]<=arr3[k+1])
                     {
                       j=arr3[k+1];
                       arr3[k]=j;
                     }
                     //printf("the value of %d of [%d] is : %d \n" ,i,k, arr3[k]);              
                }
            }  

            //here i am printing the sorted array in descending order

            for(i=0;i<s3;i++){
                printf("%d" , arr3[i]);
            }
    }
```

please also help me with inner k loop.
i think that is where i am missing something.

Comment: Normally, if you say some code is merging two arrays, it means that the values are being interleaved in the result, usually because both arrays have been sorted individually and you need to create a result that is also sorted the same way without having to re-sort the combined array.  You're simply concatenating the two arrays — which is perfectly legitimate, but isn't usually called 'merging'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
if(arr3[k]<arr3[k+1])
{
    j=arr3[k+1];
    arr3[k+1] = arr3[k];
    arr3[k]=j;
}
```